# I want to also save parent entity when save child entity by useing Spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Here is the entity code:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_user")
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    //omit other fields

    @OneToOne(cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Student student;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_student")
public class Student{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "c_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT), columnDefinition = "INT COMMENT 'user number'")
    private User user;
}
```

Here is the save code:

```java
@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired    
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired  
    private final PasswordEncoder pwdEncoder;

    @Override
    public Optional<UserBody> add(UserParam param) {
        User user = User.from(param);
        if(userRepository.countByName(user.getName()) > 0){
            throw new BusinessException("user already exists");
        }
        user.setPassword(pwdEncoder.encode(param.getPassword()));
        
        userRepository.save(user);
        user.getStudent().setUser(user);  // do this for update the column `c_user_id` of student table
        return Optional.of(UserBody.from(user));
    }
}
```

As above, when I try to save a user, It will be auto-save a student, but in the `t_student` table, the column `c_user_id` is empty. so I have to write the code `user.getStudent().setUser(user)` to update the column `c_user_id`.

so why? and what should I do to let the column `c_user_id` be auto-filled on saving user

ps: I don't want to change the `mappedBy` relation to Student, I know that could work, but I think a User can be a student, also can be another character, so if I add some other character, it will modify `t_user` table. This causes the table to become more and more bloated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Student` gets persisted. But you specified that the `Student` is responsible for maintaining the relationship between `Student` and `User`, and  since `Student.user` is `null` this gets persisted in the database.

Therefore Hibernate is literally doing what you told it to do.

Comment: oh, I got it. Because the `Student.user` can not be auto-set, so the bi-relationship can not do that